# Implementing a REST interface with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The HTTP API provided for the cloud functions mixes all HTTP methods into one API call:

```
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { ... });
```

This requires a switch to separate out the GETs, POSTs, PUTs and DELETEs. Is there a better way similar to the Express API:

```
app.get()
app.post()
app.put()
app.delete()
```

This will allow us to implement resource based endpoints more cleanly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) allows you to provide an [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) app to implement HTTP APIs (or whatever else you want to do with an Express.js app).

You can see an example of this in [this sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint).

The important thing to note is that you can create an express app, configure it with the endpoints you want, and hand it to Cloud Functions:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.user.name}`);
});
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for your quick response, @doug_stevenson

Comment: Super weird that Cloud Functions are just a wrapper around Express, but helpful, thanks.

Comment: @corysimmons Express is a very popular framework for building http apps.  It makes sense to leverage something like this because it's familiar and bulletproof.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not upset with the idea. I do wish they would've sponsored Doug Wilson before he finally burnt out (seeing as how Google's Cloud Functions are probably making millions—largely in part due to Express). In lieu of that, I wish they'd use Koa. :D