# How to add version in cloud function for firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hi I have created one cloud function `getUsers`. Its can be accessed like https://xyz.cloudfunctions.net/getUsers

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

});
```

I need to do some changes in the function and want to keep same function name. I want to add version in the cloud function so that it can be accessed like this

https://xyz.cloudfunctions.net/getUsers/v2

What is the way to do this in cloud function for Firebase ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no built-in versioning for Cloud Functions. The closest you can get on the default URLs is writing the version into the function name: `getUsers_v2`.

If you're using Firebase Hosting to give friendly URLs to your Cloud Functions, you can of course [map each individual function to the URL you want](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#directing_hosting_requests_to_your_function).

Comment: You can configure an Express app to be able to use whatever paths you want for your HTTP endpoints.  If you want to put a version string in the path, then feel free to do so.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517040/implementing-a-rest-interface-with-firebase-cloud-functions

Answer (score 11):

One way of doing is this to make your own path handler. Of course, you can use express but I chose not to use it just for this.

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

   const path = request.path;               // '/getUsers/v2'

   const version = path.split('/')[2];      // ['', 'getUsers', 'v2']

   switch ( version ) {

      case 'v1': // Handle for v1; 
             break;

      case 'v2': // Handle for v2; 
             break;
   }
});
```

This will expose your endpoint till `https://xyz.cloudfunctions.net/getUsers` but for trailing versions or any other stuff in url, you can use a handler like this.